# Doctrine hydrate only single row from native query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-native-query

Here is my mappings:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('OOHMediaBundle:OfferItem', 'i');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('i', 'reserved_at', 'reservedAt');

$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('OOHMediaBundle:Offer', 'o', 'i', 'offer');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'o_id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'continue_from', 'continueFrom');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('o', 'continue_to', 'continueTo');
```

Here is my native query:

```
$qb = $this->registry->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
    'SELECT i.reserved_at, o.id AS o_id, o.continue_from, o.continue_to
    FROM offer_item AS i
    LEFT JOIN offers AS o ON i.offer_id = o.id
    WHERE i.reserved_at IS NOT NULL
    ;',
    $rsm
);
```

If above SQL is copied into mysql client it produce **43** records.

When executed as `$qb->getArrayResult();` it only return **1** record.

When executed as `$qb->getResult();` it return exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Notice: Undefined index: offer_id
```

Where other *42* records disappeared?

Comment: Did you try with `$qb->getResult();` ?

Comment: Try adding `i.id` to the field results. As far as I remember the `AI` columns were required as well Also keep in mind the order of the select clause matters and need to match the order in `addFieldResult()`.

Comment: I do not have id in that table :( its M2M joining table without ids...

Comment: @Artamiel pls turn Your comment into answer. It was in deed what I needed. (Thankfully 'id' was also needed for various other reasons there!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, as I mentioned in my comment, when using `ResultSetMapping` the `Auto Increment` column of the main entity needs to be listed in the field set result. The following should also apply for every join clause that needs to be added, so that doctrine can format the result properly.

The order of the columns added with `addFieldResult()` have to be same as the one listed in the RAW query.

The following chapter [Examples](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples) in Doctrine's documentation contains some nice samples for further reference.

Comment: The order of the the columns doesn't have to be the same.